# Fix jumping in CSS text replacement animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a textbox that I would like to do a fancy text slide in/out effect on whenever I change the text in it. I am able to switch the text and trigger the animation and it even works multiple times, but there is a weird jumping into place/resizing of the container div that happens during the animation. I have tried animating the margins of the text elements along with the rest of the animation but that doesn't work. I can't have the div resize because it is contained in a flexbox with an image right below it that I don't want to be pushed out of the way. What can I do to fix this and make the animation smoother?

```js
function textboxWriteAnimated(str) {
    const newText = document.createElement('p');
    const currentText = document.getElementById("centerText");
    const textContainer = document.getElementById("centerTextContainer");
    newText.className = "fadingin";
    newText.innerHTML = str;
    newText.id = "centerText";
    currentText.classList.add(["fadingout"]);
    textContainer.appendChild(newText);
    setTimeout(() => {
        textContainer.removeChild(currentText);
        document.getElementById("centerText").classList.remove(["fadingin"]);
    }, 500)
}

setTimeout(() => {
    textboxWriteAnimated("Does it work?");
    setTimeout(() => {
        textboxWriteAnimated(":(");
    }, 1500)
}, 1000)
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#vert-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#centerTextContainer {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    max-height: 37px;
    min-height: 37px;
}

#img-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50vw;
}
#links-container img {
    margin: 5px;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    from {
        bottom: 0px;
        opacity: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    to {
        bottom: 25px;
        opacity: 0%;
        font-size: 4px;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        top: 25px;
        opacity: 0%;
        font-size: 4px;
    }
    to {
        top: 0px;
        opacity: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.fadingout {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.fadingin {
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="vert-container">
  <div id="centerTextContainer">
    <p id="centerText">Testing...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="img-container">
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Test-Image-black.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
function textboxWriteAnimated(str) {
    const newText = document.createElement('p');
    const currentText = document.getElementById("centerText");
    const textContainer = document.getElementById("centerTextContainer");
    newText.className = "fadingin";
    newText.innerHTML = str;
    newText.id = "centerText";
    currentText.classList.add(["fadingout"]);
    textContainer.appendChild(newText);
    setTimeout(() => {
        textContainer.removeChild(currentText);
        document.getElementById("centerText").classList.remove(["fadingin"]);
    }, 500)
}

setTimeout(() => {
    textboxWriteAnimated("Does it work?");
    setTimeout(() => {
        textboxWriteAnimated(":)");
    }, 1500)
}, 1000)
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#vert-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#centerTextContainer {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    max-height: 37px;
    min-height: 37px;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

#centerTextContainer > p {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

#img-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50vw;
}
#links-container img {
    margin: 5px;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    from {
        bottom: 0px;
        opacity: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    to {
        bottom: 25px;
        opacity: 0%;
        font-size: 4px;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        top: 25px;
        opacity: 0%;
        font-size: 4px;
    }
    to {
        top: 0px;
        opacity: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.fadingout {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.fadingin {
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="vert-container">
  <div id="centerTextContainer">
    <p id="centerText">Testing...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="img-container">
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Test-Image-black.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

The `p` elements in the animation need absolute positioning so that the `top` and `bottom` transitions will work as expected.